# YAQ about passing a variable by reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

All the answers I find for specifying a variable **by reference** in JavaScript say to use an array or object, which are passed by reference. But that doesn't solve my problem, because it is only an outer array or object that is passed by reference, not the value it contains.

```
// This fragment fails for the reason given below
var Str='';
var ArrStr=[Str];
Str+='begin ';
Debug();
Str+='end ';
function Debug()
   {
   ArrStr[0]+='debug info ';
   }
```

This naive approach fails, because Debug() only modifies the contents of `ArrStr[0]`, a separate variable from `Str`.

If I change `Str+='begin ';` to `ArrStr[0]+='begin ';` this solves my problem, I think, because it does an explicit indirection, but at the expense of reducing the simplicity or clarity of the program wherever it does appending to a string that might be debugged.

So, apparently, there is no way to specify by a global variable where Debug() should put its output (I refuse to specify the variable using a character string and `eval`). How do I change the program so that Debug() appends its output to the variable `Str`, which may be different in different parts of the program? I want Debug() to work anywhere, even when a different variable is used in place of `Str`.

Is there any way to simulate true `by reference`, or must I give up and find a less elegant way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Based on almost a day of experimentation, I've decided that my proposed way to implement by-reference in JavaScript works very well after all. If you want to pass a variable A around freely by-reference, just make it into an array of length 1: `var A=['Initial Value'];`. To pass it, just pass A. To reference it for getting or setting, just reference A[0]. You can even set A to null in order to indicate a by-reference value whose name has not been set.

I hope this helps others faced with trying to get simple values like numbers and strings to pass by reference.